# libxml2 - Why does xmlFreeNode() causes a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault, libxml2

I'm trying to minimize memory leaks caused by `libxml2`.

I free the `xmlDoc` without problem. But when I try to free `xmlNode` it causes segmentation fault. In this case, it -somehow- prevents the program from finding the file, then `xmlReadFile` returns a `NULL` pointer and consequently `xmlDocGetRootElement` also returns a `NULL` pointer and trying to accessing `root_element` causes a `segmentation fault`.

If I just commented out the lines with `xmlFreeNode()`, everything works fine.

Just to double check, I tried to check if the node pointers are not `NULL` before trying to freeing the nodes, but this doesn't help.

Why can't I free the nodes without problems?

```
int setKey(uint8 newState)
{
    xmlDocPtr doc = NULL;
    xmlNodePtr root_element = NULL;
    xmlNodePtr cur_node = NULL;

    char newChar[3];

    const char *file = "file.xml";

    doc = xmlReadFile(file, NULL, 0);

    sprintf(newChar, "%d", newState);

    root_element = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

    cur_node = root_element->children; // segmentation fault

    xmlNodeSetContent(cur_node, (const xmlChar *)newChar);

    xmlSaveFile(file, doc);

    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    if(cur_node != NULL && root_element != NULL)
    {
        xmlFreeNode(cur_node);
        xmlFreeNode(root_element);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `char newChar[3];` -->> `char newChar[10];` And: `snprintf()` is your fiend. Also: check `root_element != NULL` before dereferencing it.

Answer (score 2):

[`xmlFreeDoc`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlFreeDoc) frees a document and all descendant nodes recursively. So freeing individual nodes again causes a double-free which typically results in a segfault. If you want to keep some of the nodes after freeing the document, you have to unlink them with [`xmlUnlinkNode`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlUnlinkNode) first.

Comment: I tried not to use `xmlFreeDoc()` and use `xmlFreeNode()` instead, but this didn't work.

Comment: @nwellnhof : could you please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77844327/setting-root-element-from-the-same-xml-doc-results-in-memory-leak