# Setting root element from the same XML doc results in memory leak

Tags: c, libxml2

I have an XML as follows:

`xmlChar *xml_in`:

```
<rpc-reply xmlns:abc="http://xml.myorg.net/">
<a myorg:style="abc-myorg">
<b>Enabled</b>
<c>1</c>
</a>
<cli>
<banner></banner>
</cli>
</rpc-reply>
```

I want to covert the above to following:

```
<a myorg:style="abc-myorg">
<b>Enabled</b>
<c>1</c>
</a>
```

Here is what I'm doing:

```
void
strip_namespace (xmlNodePtr node)
{
    if (node == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    xmlSetNs(node, NULL);

    for (node = node->children; node; node = node->next) {
        strip_namespace(node);
    }
}

xmlNodePtr
get_first_element (xmlNodePtr node)
{
    for (; node; node = node->next) {
        if (node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
            return node;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}


xmlDocPtr doc;
xmlNodePtr root, tmp_node;

doc = xmlReadDoc((const xmlChar *) xml_in, NULL, NULL, XML_PARSE_NODICT);
root = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

if (0 == strcmp((const char *) root->name, "rpc-reply")) {
    root = get_first_element(root->children);
    tmp_node = xmlDocSetRootElement(doc, root);

    strip_namespace(root);
    return doc;
}
```

The `xmlDocPtr` is used to walk the tree and then later freed using `xmlFreeDoc`.

However the above results in memory leak in valgrind report, even though `xml_in` and `doc` are later freed using libxml2's appropriate `free` functions.

I understand I'm probably doing it in the wrong way, but I would appreciate if you could share the correct code snippet to illustrate how this should be done.

Please also suggest if you observe any other potential issues in the above code.

**What I tried:**
1)

```
tmp_node = xmlDocSetRootElement(doc, root);
xmlUnlinkNode(tmp_node); // Tried to unlink the node, but leaks remains the same.
```

2. 

```
tmp_node = xmlDocSetRootElement(doc, root);
xmlFreeNode(tmp_node); // Tried to free the node, but application crashes.
```

3. 

```
tmp_node = xmlDocSetRootElement(doc, root);
xmlUnlinkNode(tmp_node); // Tried to unlink the node first.
xmlFreeNode(tmp_node); // Tried to free the node, but application crashes.
```

4. Instead of `xmlDocSetRootElement` tried to use `xmlReplaceNode`:

`new_root = get_first_element(root->children);`

`root = xmlReplaceNode(root, new_root);`

Leaks still remain the same.
Then I tried adding `xmlUnlinkNode(root)` and `xmlFreeNode(root)`  after `xmlReplaceNode` similar to above 3 combination i.e. 1), 2), 3) but the behavior is same.

Comment: `tmp_node` (the previous root) probably needs to be freed. Not sure if you need to disconnect the new root from it first, would guess so.

Comment: I have just updated my questions with what I tried, please check. I tried `xmlUnlinkNode(tmp_node)`, leaks still remain the same. Then I also added `xmlFreeNode(tmp_node)` with it, and the application started crashing because of use after free I think. doc is being used after this function. But my assumption is that when the node is unlinked/freed then why should it be a problem while doing stuff with `doc` or freeing it.

Comment: It’s not `tmp_node` you would need to remove to implement my suggestion – it’s `root` from `tmp_node`. So maybe `xmlUnlinkNode(root); tmp_node = xmlDocSetRootElement(doc, root); xmlFreeNode(tmp_node);`.

Comment: Tried: `root = get_first_element(root->children); xmlUnlinkNode(root); tmp_node = xmlDocSetRootElement(doc, root); xmlFreeNode(tmp_node);`. Application crashes..

Comment: btw, `xmlDocSetRootElement` does `xmlUnlinkNode` on the 2nd argument anyway..

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer if you post a complete, self-contained test case.

Comment: The code snippet mentioned in the question is sufficient to recreate the mem leak.